# How to visualize a Swing code from one IDE in another IDE

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, netbeans

I've built a Java GUI on NetBeans and used it in IntelliJ because I couldn't make float design in IntelliJ. Is there any way to visualize my code into the design in IntelliJ to fix some problem?

Comment: Ok, sounds like you're trying to use form editors. Simple answer here is, don't, for the very reason you've just described, plus, they make a mess of your code and encourage poor code designs

Comment: If you must, you can [import Netbeans project into Intellij](https://www.javatpoint.com/intellij-idea-migrating-from-netbeans)